# Full-text search optimization in Oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle, doctrine-orm, query-optimization

Welcome,
I have an optimization problem with Oracle database. I want to search for some objects that matches the text that front-end user types into search-box. I use PHP with Doctrine in my application, and Doctrine generates code like following:

```
SELECT p0_."BD"     AS BD --...

FROM "P" p0_
LEFT JOIN "G" g1_ ON p0_.GID = g1_.ID
LEFT JOIN "PD" p2_ ON p0_.PDID = p2_.ID
LEFT JOIN "PI" p3_ ON p2_.ID = p3_.PDID --ONE TO MANY, SO OPERATOR 'IN' REQUIRED
LEFT JOIN "IT" i4_ ON i4_.ID = p3_.ITID
LEFT JOIN "A" a5_ ON p0_.AID = a5_.ID
LEFT JOIN "P" p6_ ON p0_.MPID = p6_.ID
LEFT JOIN "RS" r7_ ON p0_.RSID = r7_.ID
WHERE (((
LOWER(p2_."FN") LIKE '%abc%'
OR LOWER(p2_."GN") LIKE '%abc%'
OR LOWER(a5_."SN") LIKE '%abc%'
OR LOWER(a5_."CN") LIKE '%abc%'
OR LOWER(a5_."CON") LIKE '%abc%'))
OR p2_."ID" IN
  (SELECT p8_."ID"
  FROM "PI" p9_
  LEFT JOIN "PD" p8_
  ON p9_.PDID = p8_.ID
  WHERE LOWER(p9_."VALUE") LIKE '%abc%'
  ))
AND p6_."ID" = p0_."ID";
```

Database is rather big (~half milion rows) and it takes about 40 seconds before system returns result.

"Explain Plan" in SQL Developer shows that system uses HASH JOINs with FULL TABLE ACCESS. Using nested loops doesn't change things much (even with INDEXes).

Is it possible to optimize this process somehow?

**EDIT**

Following query returns the same result but it is lot faster (1.5s):

```
SELECT p0_."BD"     AS BD --...

FROM "P" p0_
LEFT JOIN "G" g1_ ON p0_.GID = g1_.ID
LEFT JOIN "PD" p2_ ON p0_.PDID = p2_.ID
LEFT JOIN "PI" p3_ ON p2_.ID = p3_.PDID
LEFT JOIN "IT" i4_ ON i4_.ID = p3_.ITID
LEFT JOIN "A" a5_ ON p0_.AID = a5_.ID
LEFT JOIN "P" p6_ ON p0_.MPID = p6_.ID
LEFT JOIN "RS" r7_ ON p0_.RSID = r7_.ID
WHERE 
p0_.id IN
(
    SELECT p0_A.id FROM "P" p0_A JOIN "PD" p2_A ON (p0_A.PDID = p2_A.ID AND (LOWER(p2_."GN") LIKE '%abc%' OR LOWER(p2_."FN") LIKE '%abc%'))
    UNION
    SELECT p0_B.id FROM "P" p0_B LEFT JOIN "PD" p2_B ON p0_B.PDID = p2_B.ID JOIN "PI" p3_B ON (p2_B.ID = p3_B.PDID AND(LOWER(p3_B."VALUE") LIKE '%abc%'))
    --UNION ANOTHER SELECTS
)
AND p6_."ID" = p0_."ID";
```

The trick is to add additional condition in ON part of query and do JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN. It must be subquery, because the trick will work only with one table's fields. Unfortunetely, Doctrine does not support UNION clausule. Is Oracle that stupid with its optimization mechanizm or am I missing something? Maybe I could modify query somehow?

Greathings!

Comment: I don't suppose that Doctrine would have the ability to use an Oracle Text query rather than a LIKE with leading and trailing wildcards?

Comment: 1. I can use Oracle-specific functions in Doctrine, but I can not use UNION clausule as it is not function. But can you provide Oracle-specific query that will work faster than LIKE '%foo%'?

2. I don't thing that LIKE operator is a problem. How can you explain that second query works faster?

Comment: @Mariusz Jaskółka, it's a known fact - union works faster than or. Oracle does not rewrite queries with or.
You need to perform full-text search faster, right? Because it's not that obvious from your question and that monster-query says nothing about your tables

Comment: right. Unfortunetely, it is not fresh thread and I can not test other solutions right now (We've decided to use elasticsearch). As far as I remember, operator "SELECT" inside "IN" is the biggest problem here. The most wired is fact, that optimization in Oracle Database Engine seems to be poor. But maybe there is a reason I can't see right now.

Answer (score 0):

without beeing able to test the code, could this be what you are after?

```
SELECT P0_."BD"     AS BD --...

FROM "P" P0_
LEFT JOIN "G" g1_ ON p0_.GID = g1_.ID
LEFT JOIN "PD" P2_ ON P0_.PDID = P2_.ID
LEFT JOIN "PI" p3_ ON p2_.ID = p3_.PDID
LEFT JOIN "IT" I4_ ON I4_.ID = P3_.ITID
LEFT JOIN "A" a5_ ON p0_.AID = a5_.ID
LEFT JOIN "P" P6_ ON P0_.MPID = P6_.ID
LEFT JOIN "RS" r7_ ON p0_.RSID = r7_.ID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT P0_A.ID FROM "P" P0_A JOIN "PD" P2_A ON (P0_A.PDID = P2_A.ID AND (LOWER(P2_."GN") LIKE '%abc%' OR LOWER(P2_."FN") LIKE '%abc%'))) XX ON P0_.ID = XX.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT P0_B.ID FROM "P" P0_B LEFT JOIN "PD" P2_B ON P0_B.PDID = P2_B.ID JOIN "PI" P3_B ON (P2_B.ID = P3_B.PDID AND(LOWER(P3_B."VALUE") LIKE '%abc%'))) YY ON P0_.ID = YY.ID

WHERE P6_."ID" = P0_."ID"
and (XX.ID is not null or XX.ID is not null);
```